# What is the remainder of $\frac{2^{2015}}{36}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am unfamiliar with modular arithmetic. I am attempting to solve this problem as practice for [mathleague](http://mathleague.org/) competitions.

In an attempt to solve this problem, I first attempted to define what the remainder is by the following expression:
$$2^{2015} - 36\left\lfloor{\frac{2^{2015}}{36}}\right\rfloor$$
Which can be simplified to...
$$2^{2015} - 36\left\lfloor{\frac{2^{2013}}{9}}\right\rfloor$$
After that though, I didn't know what I should do. I thought about rewriting the original expression all in terms of $2^x$ like so...
$$\frac{2^{2015}}{2^5+2^2}$$
Yet that still wasn't helpful.

This morning, I finally realized that $2^{k+dx}\mod36$, where $k$ and $d$ are constants, has a pattern that must repeat itself at some point since the result of the operation must be an integer greater than 0 and less than 36 (it has a finite set of possible results).

I know that 2015 is divisible by 5. And using a calculator I found out that...
$$2^5\mod{36} = 2^{35}\mod{36}$ = 32$$
To test if I had found a solution, I verified that there was an integer solution to the following equation (plugging values in for $k$ and $d$ above):
$$5 + 30x = 2015$$
And found that $x=67$, so therefore the remainder of $\dfrac{2^{2015}}{36}$ must be $32$.

Is there a faster and/or better approach to this particular problem or problems like these?

Comment: +1 for figuring this out on your own. And +1 for asking for a better way. If you're interested in math competitions you'd do well to learn the Euclidean algorithm and Euler's theorem (as in @Leg 's answer).

Comment: [This post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand) might be useful for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $\gcd(2,9) = 1$, we have from Euler's theorem, that $2^{\phi(9)} \equiv 1 \pmod{9} \implies 2^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$

This gives us that
$$2^{2010} \equiv 1 \pmod9 \implies 2^{2015} \equiv 2^5 \pmod9 \equiv 5 \pmod9$$

This means the only solutions can be $5,14,23,32 \pmod{36}$. Further, since $2^{2015}$ is divisible by $4$, the only possible solution is
$$2^{2015} \equiv 32 \pmod{36}$$

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with euler's theorem, but I accepted your answer on account of that it gave me a theorem to research for solving future problems like these.

Answer (score 0):

not much familiar with modular division but surely can give simpler method $2015=13.31.5$ implying $\frac{2^{5}}{36}$ would yield same result as its one of the prime multiples of $2015$ now we can calculate $2^{5}=32$ so remainder when $32$ is divided by $36$ is $32$ . hope its clear